# XAML can't find the converter class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I'm displaying a popup with the following code:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=categoryTagEditorControl}"
       Placement="Bottom">
    <Popup.IsOpen>
        <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanOrConverter}">
            <Binding Mode="OneWay" ElementName="categoryTagEditorControl" Path="IsMouseOver"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsMouseOver" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Popup.IsOpen>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="Some Text.."/>
        <DatePicker/>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

Here's the code of BooleanOrConverter:

```
public class BooleanOrConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        foreach (object booleanValue in values)
        {
            if (booleanValue is bool == false)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("BooleanOrConverter only accepts boolean as datatype");
            }
            if ((bool)booleanValue == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

and its placed into PopupTest.InfoPanels.Windows namespace

when I run this, I'm getting following exception:

```
Cannot find resource named 'BooleanOrConverter'. Resource names are case sensitive.
```

What should I change for this to work?

Comment: Try adding an object of your converter class to the relevant resource dictionary and then use `DynamicResource <resource_id>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like your Multibinding doesn't know where to look for the converter. Have you defined the converter as a [staticresource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx)? You can either specify the converter in the control's resources or in the included [ResourceDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.aspx). Add a reference to the converter's namespace and then define a ResourceKey for it. Something like:

```
<UserControl 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyConverters">

     <UserControl.Resources>
          <converters:BooleanOrConverter x:Key="BoolOrConverter"/>
     </UserControl.Resources>

    ... // use converter as you were before

 </UserControl>
```

Comment: Use <converters:BooleanOrConverter x:Key="BooleanOrConverter"/>. Changed the key just to avoid confusion.